# Change @State in a @ViewBuilder closure

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to understand how to change `@State` variables in `@ViewBuilder` closures. The following is just a simple example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var width = CGFloat(0)

    var body: some View { //Error 1
        GeometryReader { geometry in //Error 2
            self.width = geometry.size.width
            return Text("Hello world!")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting some errors:

Error 1:

> Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements
>   in its body from which to infer an underlying type

But the `return` is redundant because there's only one line of code inside the `View` computed property.

Error 2:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'GeometryReader<_>' to return
>   type 'some View'

Since I explicitly write `return Text("...")` shouldn't the type be clear?

What's the problem here?

Comment: Embed your `GeometryReader` inside a `VStack` and also delete your `return` statement. This will get rid of the `View` related errors but I'm not sure how to deal with the error that you'll get with `self.width = geometry.size.width`. I think this is fundamentally the problem. The compiler errors in SwiftUI don't always show you the underlying cause of the error.

Comment: I don't think the VStack is necessary here. There's only one element inside the View and it's the GeometryReader. So it should be fine. The return statement, instead, is necessary because Swift can't infer the return type in a multiline closure.

Comment: I know, but what happens is that the compiler is giving you an error that unrelated to your underlying issue, so by using a VStack, you're just silencing the most proximate cause of the compiler error in order to find out what the underlying issue is. In this case, the issue is the assignment statement -- it may very well not be allowed within a ViewBuilder closure. You can't even use `if let` inside of a ViewBuilder closure.

Comment: I get your point. I agree with you that the errors the compiler is giving me are likely unrelated to the real issue. On the other hand it seems very strange to me that I just can't refer to my instance variable within those closures. Or at least we should be able to find some docu about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can't make arbitrary swift statements in a `functionBuilder`. There is a specific syntax allowed. In SwiftUI's case, it's a `ViewBuilder`, which under the hood is composing your type. When you make consecutive statements in SwiftUI, you are actually relying on the compiler to compose a new type underneath according to the rules of that DSL.

2nd, SwiftUI is a recipe, it's not an event system. You *don't* change state variables in the `body` function, you set up how things should react when state variables change externally. If you want another view to react in some way to that width, you need to define that content with respect to the width of the component you want. Without knowing what your ultimate goal is here, it's hard to answer how to relate the content to each other.

EDIT:

I was asked to elaborate on what exactly is allowed. Each `functionBuilder` has a different allowable syntax which is defined in the `functionBuilder` itself. This has a good overview on function builders in Swift 5.1: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/the-swift-51-features-that-power-swiftuis-api

As for what SwiftUI is specifically looking for, it's essentially looking for each statement to return an instance of `View`.

```
// works fine!
VStack {
  Text("Does this")
  Text("Work?")
}

// doesn't work!
VStack {
  Text("Updating work status...")
  self.workStatus = .ok // this doesn't return an instance of `View`!
}

// roundabout, but ok...
VStack {
  Text("Being clever")
  gimmeView()
}

// fine to execute arbitrary code now, as long as we return a `View`
private func gimmeView() -> some View {
    self.workingStatus = .roundabout 
    return Text("Yes, but it does work.")
}
```

This is why you got the obtuse error you got:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'GeometryReader<_>' to return type 'some View'

The type system can't construct any `View` out of `View` and essentially `Void` when you execute:

> self.width = geometry.size.width

When you do consecutive `View` statements, underneath, it's still being converted into a new type of `View`:

```
// the result of this is TupleView<Text, Text>
Text("left")
Text("right")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You said "[...] There is a specific syntax allowed. [...]" and that's exactly what I'm looking for. The example in the question is just a silly example, but I'd really like to understand what we can and what we can't code in those closures. The answer might even be "nothing more than a list of expressions of the same type needed to build the final type" and it will be perfectly fine to me. But I'm struggling to find these theoretical (very important) information. If you can link me some documentation/blog post/GitHub readme/whatever it would be great. Thank you.

Comment: I edited my answer and provided a lot more guidance.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me find this other useful link https://blog.vihan.org/swift-function-builders/ and this GitHub page from Apple https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/9992cf3c11c2d5e0ea20bee98657d93902d5b174/proposals/XXXX-function-builders.md